# Display Pandas Dataframe PowerBI

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

PowerBi does not allow display of pandas dataframe in page. Requires a plot.

I am working with the python scripting function in PowerBi. I would like to display a pandas dataframe in the page but when I try to print(dataset) I get the following error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BWvT.png)

Is there a neat way to display a pandas table in the page? Also, if there is a lot or rows in the data, I would like to be able to scroll through it in the page.

Comment: The Python visual turns data into an image. You can use the [Python step in Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-in-query-editor) if you want to output the Dataframe for use in your report. Added from link-only answer by [David Browne - Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft)